# how to get the image in the user screen whien using slimbox popup in facebook long iframe?

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, iframe, mootools

I'm using [Slimbox 1.8](http://www.digitalia.be/software/slimbox) to get a pop up image when user click on link

all is good till now, but when I use this site in to be facebook iframe and after I remove the iframe scroll,

the image appear in the middle of the iframe that is not in the user screen "the iframe is too long"

I search and found that the slimbox changing the "top" style element of the image

it use this line to make it in the middle:

```
s=h.offsetHeight;    
var P=Math.max(0,y-(s/2)),N=0,O;
```

I'm asking if there is any way to get the user click position and start the popup on?

Slimbox is using MooTools

Regards,

Comment: you want to find when the user clicks on an image inside your iframe based upon coordinates?

Comment: Did you get this working? Please answer Dimitar's question so your problem is more clear.

Comment: I still didn't solve it :(

Comment: my question is how to get the click coordinates?

Comment: Do you mean you want to have a iFrame with facebook inside and when you click on it open slimbox on the same spot as mouse click? Do you have control over the iframe's content? can you add code there?

Comment: I want to add my iframe within facebook page, like this: https://www.facebook.com/GoDaddy/app_208195102528120

inside my iframe I have slimbox and I want to make appear in the position the mouse click on

Comment: You mean inside facebook? not you own website. (sorry for many questions, just trying to get it clear)

Comment: yes it's inside facebook, I just can modify in the iframe